# Graph query on SharePoint Libraray with Paging

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I have libraries containing way more than 5000 files
When using:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/3a8180fe-ca21-40a8-81e6-0950f5966f07/lists/DPC Documents/Items?top=499&$expand=fields&$filter=fields/FileLeafRef eq '0100.009_Client Name_Physician Name_FMV Exhibits_466689.XLSX'`

I Get error "The request is unprocessable because it uses too many resources"
I can I ask for it to be paged?

BTW equivalent SharePoint REST call returns "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold."

So there is no way to look for items in lists containing more than 5000 items.
I noticed I can't publish major version programmatically in such libraries.

I MS not supporting any API to work with this?

Thanks

Comment: Would you kindly share the request-ids and responses for both ms graph and sharepoint api so we can look into this ?

Comment: The error for publish (await projectWebSite.getFileByServerRelativeUrl("/teams/" + dItem.dpcProjectNumber + "/DPCDocuments/" + fileName).publish("Rename Existing File"); ) is "Error making HttpClient request in queryable [500] Internal Server Error ::> {"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024860, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold."}}}"

Comment: The error for SP REST (/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('DPC%20Documents')/items?$expand=File&$select=Id%2CRequestNumber%2CModified%2CFile%2FName&$top=1000&$filter=FileLeafRef%20eq%20%27ReplaceMe.docx%27) is: "{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "-2147024860, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en-US",
      "value": "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold."
    }
  }
}"

Comment: The error for Graph (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/3a8180fe-ca21-40a8-81e6-0950f5966f07/Lists/DPC Documents/items?expand=Fields&$top=1&$filter=fields/FileLeafRef eq 'SRH ASC and Endo Development Proposal.docx') with header Prefer:HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly is : in the next comment

Comment: graph error:""error": {
        "code": "notSupported",
        "message": "The request is unprocessable because it uses too many resources",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-06-03T13:44:54",
            "request-id": "d91af364-86c5-4c57-acb3-7a2ef1db4150",
            "client-request-id": "f086a047-cf9e-ae28-0287-10d91f26db4f"
        }
    }"   Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably due to the reason that you have more than 5000 files in the doc library and the filter column FileLeafRef is not indexed (you cannot add index this column either). I encountered same error when filtering with a custom metadata column but fortunately after adding the index to the column, the error went away. The only solution to your problem is not to use FileLeafRef as your filter column but use the Title column in the filter condition, after ensuring that Title column is populated with name of the document and the column is indexed.

Comment: This is not working evenif I have added index. I am quering data from the list by filtering the records using Modified column. I have added index on Modified column as well as I have tried to use Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly

Comment: Please note: I have around 15000+ records in SharePoint list